Discriminating TypeScript function return type from args without using generics
In TypeScript, I know you can use function overloading or generics to implement polymorphism:

Function overloading
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add(a: string, b: string): string
function add(a: unknown, b: unknown): number | string {
  // implementation here
}

const num = add(1, 2)
//     ^? number
const str = add('1', '2')
//     ^? string


Generics
type PrimitiveOf<A extends string | number> = A extends string
  ? string
  : A extends number
    ? number
    : never

const add = <A extends string | number, B extends PrimitiveOf<A> = PrimitiveOf<A>>(
  a: A,
  b: B,
): PrimitiveOf<A> => {
  // implementation here
}

const num = add(1, 2)
//     ^? number
const str = add('1', '2')
//     ^? string



My problem is I'm implementing a library, Onion.JS, which manipulates generic functions, and I'd like to get this polymorphism as the output of a generic computation. Correct me if I'm wrong, but both solutions cannot apply here.
The closest I can get to is by using discriminated tuple for args, but the control flow doesn't recognize the return type:
type PrimitiveOf<A extends string | number> = A extends string
  ? string
  : A extends number
    ? number
    : never

type PolymorphicFn<TUPLES extends (string | number)[]> = <TUPLE extends TUPLES>(
  ...args: TUPLE
) => PrimitiveOf<TUPLE[number]>

const isFirstElementString = (tuple: unknown[]): tuple is [string, ...unknown[]] =>
  typeof tuple[0] === 'string'

const isFirstElementNumber = (tuple: unknown[]): tuple is [number, ...unknown[]] =>
  typeof tuple[0] === 'number'

// ❌ `add` is not assignable to `PolymorphicFn` as return type is not matched
const add: PolymorphicFn<[string, string] | [number, number]> = (...tuple) => {
  if (isFirstElementString(tuple)) {
    // b is typed as string
    const [a, b] = tuple

    return `${a}${b}`
  }

  if (isFirstElementNumber(tuple)) {
    // b is typed as number
    const [a, b] = tuple

    return a + b
  }
}

const num = add(1, 2)
//     ^? number
const str = add('1', '2')
//     ^? string

Is there a way to include the return type of the function in the discrimination? Thanks!

You can use type casting to the returned values, also the second if statement isn't required, and your function paths must all return a value: Playground

No, it's essentially a missing feature of TS, see ms/TS#33912 and the linked q/a above.
